# Perform Canny Edge in HSV Image

Tags: opencv, colors, hsv

I had converted an BGR image to HSV to detect the black circles, then how I perform Canny edge on the HSV image? I had tried but it doesn't works at all.

```
IplImage *capturedImg = cvLoadImage("template.jpg",1);
IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(capturedImg), 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(capturedImg, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(capturedImg), 8, 1);

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(0, 0,0), cvScalar(255, 255, 38),imgThreshed);
cvShowImage("HSV",imgThreshed);
IplImage*cannyImg2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgThreshed),8,1);
cvCanny(grayscaleImg2,cannyImg2,0,255,3);
 cvShowImage("canny2",cannyImg2);
```

The first image is eyes detection, then I use HSV image to detect the pupil, so how can I know the position of pupils and its radius?
[image]

Comment: please add a sample image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line:

```
cvCanny(grayscaleImg2, cannyImg2, 0, 255, 3);
```

should instead be:

```
cvCanny(imgThreshed, cannyImg2, 0, 255, 3);
```

because you want to find the contours on the thresholded mask.